# GtkTreeView does not show all rows when in a GtkBox

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I have the following MWE:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

//#define USE_BOX

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    GtkTreeStore *ts = gtk_tree_store_new(1, G_TYPE_STRING);
    GtkWidget *tv = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model(GTK_TREE_MODEL(ts));
    GtkCellRenderer *renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
    gtk_tree_view_insert_column_with_attributes(
        GTK_TREE_VIEW(tv), -1, "title", renderer, "text", 0, NULL
    );
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 500, 400);

#ifdef USE_BOX
    GtkWidget *box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
    GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new("label");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), label, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), tv, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), box);
    gtk_widget_show(label);
    gtk_widget_show(box);
#else
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), tv);
#endif

    GtkTreeIter iter;
    GtkTreeIter subiter;
    gtk_tree_store_append(ts, &iter, NULL);
    gtk_tree_store_set(ts, &iter, 0, "1", -1);
    gtk_tree_store_append(ts, &subiter, &iter);
    gtk_tree_store_set(ts, &subiter, 0, "1.1", -1);
    gtk_tree_store_append(ts, &subiter, &iter);
    gtk_tree_store_set(ts, &subiter, 0, "1.2", -1);
    gtk_tree_store_append(ts, &subiter, &iter);
    gtk_tree_store_set(ts, &subiter, 0, "1.3", -1);
    gtk_tree_store_append(ts, &subiter, &iter);
    gtk_tree_store_set(ts, &subiter, 0, "1.4", -1);
    gtk_tree_store_append(ts, &subiter, &iter);
    gtk_tree_store_set(ts, &subiter, 0, "1.5", -1);

    gtk_tree_store_append(ts, &iter, NULL);
    gtk_tree_store_set(ts, &iter, 0, "2", -1);
    gtk_tree_store_append(ts, &subiter, &iter);
    gtk_tree_store_set(ts, &subiter, 0, "2.1", -1);
    gtk_tree_store_append(ts, &subiter, &iter);
    gtk_tree_store_set(ts, &subiter, 0, "2.2", -1);
    gtk_tree_store_append(ts, &subiter, &iter);
    gtk_tree_store_set(ts, &subiter, 0, "2.3", -1);

    gtk_widget_show(tv);
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Now in this code, if `USE_BOX` is not defined (as in the above), then everything works as expected. But if we define `USE_BOX` such that the GtkTreeView is placed in a GtkBox, then we have the following problem:

At first, the window looks normal:

[image: normal window]

But when I click on the "triangle" next to "1" to expand the row, some of the children (as well as the "2" row) are missing:

[image: missing rows]

What I expect it to show (i.e. the behaviour when not placed in a GtkBox):

[image: expected behaviour]

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this some kind of bug in GTK+?

I have tried using a GtkGrid instead of a GtkBox but the result is the same. However, in both cases if I expand the "2" row before the "1" row, then everything works as expected.

If it matters, I use the following to compile the file:

```
 gcc -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wpedantic `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 gmodule-2.0` ./mwe.c -o ./mwe `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 gmodule-2.0`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking if you call `gtk_box_pack_start()` with both `expand` and `fill` set to FALSE, the child widget will use as little space as it can. I'm not entirely sure what the TreeView is supposed to do when rows are then expanded... there may indeed be a bug in the behaviour as it doesn't seem consistent.

Still, you almost certainly want to do

```
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), tv, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
```

instead. This way the TreeView expands to all available vertical space. You may also want to put the TreeView inside a ScrolledWindow if you think the expanded rows might not fit in the viewport at once -- as you've seen the TreeView does not have scrollbars on it's own.

Comment: Wow. Actually just by putting the tree view into a scrolled window this can be solved. (I guess this is because the tree view will fill up all the space of the scrolled window.) Thank you very much.

Comment: The `expand` and `fill` bits will still be important once you put that GtkScrolledWindow inside another GtkBox. (Alternatively, you can set the `hexpand`, `halign`, `vexpand`, and `valign` properties on the scrolled window itself; all GtkWidgets have these.)